# ¿Como quitar la opción de cargar images por URL en tinyMCE 6?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Requiero que el editor solamente permite cargar imagenes y que estas no se carguen a través de la URL como por defecto el editor permite

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el apartado de cargar este por defecto y que el tab de General no esté, he buscado la documentación pero al parecer no tienen una configuración para esto, intenté ocultarlo mediante código de javascript pero esa modal que muestro en la imagen se crea y se destruye cuando damos click en el icono de imagen que está en incrustado el editor lo que hace que los elementos DOMS de cargar y de General no existan al momento de ejecución de ese codigo

```
    tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  language: "es",
  branding: false,
  plugins: "image autoresize",
  toolbar: "image",
  automatic_uploads: true,
  file_picker_types: "image",
  relative_urls: false,
  images_upload_handler: img_handler,
  image_uploadtab: true,
  typeahead_urls: false,
});

const divs = $(".tox-dialog__body-nav-item");
divs.each(function (i, e) {
  if (e.textContent === "General") {
    e.remove();
    divs[++i].trigger("click");
  }
});
```

¿Existe alguna manera de quitar el apartado General de mi editor?

Comment: Agrega tu codigo

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux Lo siento, error mío de no haber puesto el codigo fuente

Comment: Como se llama ese componente en donde aparece ese modal?, como aparece en la libreria

Comment: Me crees si te digo que usando el codepen [de la documentación](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/) no logro replicar lo que muestras? Siempre sale el botón junto al campo donde se pone la URL de la imagen :/

Comment: esa modal aparece mas que todo porque estoy usando [images_upload_handler](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#images_upload_handler)

Comment: El apartado general y cargar lo agregaste tu al modal o ya existía?, estoy intentando pero no me aparecen esos labels

Comment: Ese apartado ya viene con el plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando la implementación del [código fuente](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/blob/develop/modules/tinymce/src/plugins/image/main/ts/ui/Dialog.ts#L282) de esa librería y no hay forma de quitar ese tab, por lo menos no a través de la api de la librería o las opciones porque se va a mostrar siempre que pongas un `images_upload_handler` o `images_upload_url`.

La única manera de ocultarlo sería con CSS y haciendo click programáticamente del tab de "cargar". El siguiente extracto de código es una implementación fea pero funciona:

```
// CSS:
.tox-dialog .tox-dialog__body-nav .tox-tab.tox-dialog__body-nav-item:first-child {
  display: none;
}

// Javascript:
function showUploadTabOnInit() {
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    var selector =
      '.tox-dialog .tox-dialog__body-nav .tox-tab.tox-dialog__body-nav-item:nth-child(2)';
    var tab = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (tab) tab.click();
  });

  var dialogContainer = document.querySelector('body > .tox.tox-tinymce-aux');
  observer.observe(dialogContainer, {
    childList: true,
  });
}

tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  ...
  init_instance_callback: showUploadTabOnInit,
});

// NOTA: Los selectores css usados están basados en como renderiza la vista la última versión de esta librería, si usas una versión diferente o este código no funciona asegurate de poner los selectores correctos...
```

Básicamente consiste en detectar cada vez que se abre el diálogo de subir imagen para hacer click en el tab "cargar".

Comment: Espero que en futuras versiones haya una amplia parametrización del editor, por lo pronto me quedo satisfecho con tu respuesta, me funcionó tal y como quería.